# How do I get the top n search keywords from google?

Tags: google-search, python

I need the top billion or so google search results for a project I'm working on.

I've tried using google-trends api to find this data, but it only gives me the top 10 - 20 results. https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily?geo=US

I tried using pytrends to no avail.

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()

# Get Google Top Charts
pytrend.top_charts(2020, geo='GLOBAL') #gets only 10 results

#Google Trending today
pytrend.trending_searches() #gets only 20 results
```

Some sources claim to have the top 100 searches and beyond:

https://www.semrush.com/blog/most-searched-keywords-google/

https://ahrefs.com/blog/top-google-searches/

It costs a lot money to use their services, but I don't need their SEO, I just need some of the same data they claim to have. I could happily start with the top google searches of 2010 to get my proof of concept going. Why would that data be worth anything if it exists?

Is it possible to get this data somehow? Is the only way to blindly trust some third party and cough up enough cash?

Or is there another way?

Comment: In order to click one button (or run one function) and have the answer plop itself out on your desk, at that quantity, you'll need a STAT account (in and of itself a small fortune) or something like Sistrix, Ahrefs, Majestic, or SEMrush + api keys

Comment: Is there any way I can just get old data that somebody else generated years ago? Or better yet, can one person realistically make an algorithm that slowly collects this data from somewhere? Also, what is a STAT account?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it appears to be about programatically accessing Google search results and not related to running your own website.